# Sourcetree Failed to push some refs to repository

Tags: git, branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I use Sourcetree as my version control system with a master and a develop branch, feature, hotfix and release branches.
Accidentally I was on branch master, committed to it and pushed to origin where I should have committed to my feature branch feature/new-design.
When doing the git flow release process now I get two errors described below and therefore bitbucket doesn´t trigger a deployment on the connected dploy.io.
The question is: How can I get back my beloved git flow process withour errors? :)

Details:
There where no commits, I made the following steps immediately after I have done a release already - just to show you what´s going on :)

1) Git flow finish feature new-design (while keeping it) works without errors

```
Summary of actions:
- The feature branch 'feature/new-design' was merged into 'develop'
- Feature branch 'feature/new-design' is still available
- You are now on branch 'develop'
Completed successfully.
```

2) Being on development then and starting a new release works without errors

Summary of actions:
- A new branch 'release/1.7j' was created, based on 'develop'
- You are now on branch 'release/1.7j'

```
Follow-up actions:
- Bump the version number now!
- Start committing last-minute fixes in preparing your release
- When done, run:
 git flow release finish '1.7j'
Completed successfully.
```

3) Being on release 1.7j and finishing it, throws the errors. 
Parameters used: tag with message, delete branch and push changes to remote.

```
Switched to branch 'master'
Deleted branch release/1.7j (was d1277f5).
Everything up-to-date
Everything up-to-date
To 'this is the correct address of the repo'
 * [new tag]         1.7j -> 1.7j
error: unable to delete 'release/1.7j': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'this is the correct address of the repo'

Could not delete the remote release/1.7j in origin.
Completed with errors, see above.
```

4) After clicking Close the master branch looks like in the following picture:

[image: branch master]

Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 2):

Solution:
I saw that in bitbucket the branches develop, feature/new-design and release-1.7 weren´t there, only branch master.
Directly before finishing a release I pushed to origin and selected every branch (master, develop, new-design and release) so the branches were added by bitbucket. When finishing the release everything worked like a charm then and dploy automatically did the incremental deployment.